# Can't Jump in FPS

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am following an FPS  tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_QajrabyTJc). Unfortunately, at the end when Brackeys  tests out the code, I cannot jump. Here is my player movement script:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController controller;

    public float speed = 10f;
    public float gravity = -10f;
    public float jumpHeight = 5f;

    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
    public LayerMask groundMask;

    Vector3 velocity;
    bool isGrounded;

    void Update()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

        if (isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
        {
            velocity.y = -2f;
        }

        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;

        controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetButton("Jump") && isGrounded)
        {
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
        }

        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Here is the screenshot for the code component in the unity editor:
[image: Player Movement Component]

Please help me!
Also, if you need any clarification, do not hesitate to ask!

Comment: Does isGrounded ever equal true?

Comment: It could be `isGrounded` false. Can you show your hierarchy? Where is your GroundCheck? Is it positioned correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have some suggestions for your problem but I am not 100% sure that they will work.

- Check that that the layer `Ground` is attached to the gameobject that is your platform. If you don't know how to do this, check this doc on layers: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html
- Another idea is that of the groundcheck. Make sure the ground check is just below the player.
- My final suggestion is that of the key bindings. **Make sure that Jump is assigned to your desired button.**

I believe these will work. If there are still any problems, comment down below.

Comment: thanks! I found out I didn't set the layer for my ground object to the ground layer

Comment: Yeah, I had the _exact_ same problem when I was trying out the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried the code myself yet, but if you increase the Jumpheight to something like 300 the player should jump up.

This is because your formula:

```
velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
```

Ends up being smaller than the gravity , so you don't have enough force to jump up.

Answer (score 0):

No need for ground check from Brackeys's FPS code since the character controller has its public isGrounded property.